# How to persist the image selected from gallery on the layout even if we returned to the activity again?

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

I have a `RelativeLayout` in which I have an `ImageView`. I am selecting an image for it from the gallery.

I used an `Intent` to go to another `Activity`. When I returned to the first `Activity`, my image from the gallery was not there.

I want to display the gallery image on the screen even if I returned to the `Activity`.

Comment: Could you explain further your problem?

Comment: I want to display the image selected from gallery whenever i returned to the activity.This is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to do this, you can save the image URI selected from the gallery in your `SharedPreferences` or maybe you have a database in your sistem in which to save the URI.

Every time you get into that activity check your `SharedPreferences`or your database, if you get null (or false or whatever you decide) it will be empty, otherwise you will load the Image.

This is all I can think about with the information you gave.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually my problem is "my activity is not holding the state from which i have moved to another activity to take a edit text input to the first activity". When i return back to the first activity,i am getting my string input to the first activity but the activity is not in the state from which i have left that.It appears like it has newly created with my string input.

Comment: Are you using an `Intent` to go from your second activity to the first one?, or just calling `finish()`?

Comment: If you use an intent to call to the first activiy it will reset itself. Try calling just to finish in your second activity to come back to the first one.